# Spark Framework cookies always null

Tags: java, react-native, cookies, axios, spark-java

This is my first post, so I hope I do everything right.

So, my problem is that every time I set a cookie in Spark Framework it is null as soon as I want to access it. This is, what my browser (IE/Edge) receives when I send my request:

[image: Response]

This is my Spark server:

```js
 public Server(int port, boolean skipPort) {
  isRunning = true;
  if(!skipPort)
   port(port);

  post("/login", new Route() {
   public Object handle(Request req, Response res) throws Exception {
    
    String body = req.body();
    
    JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(body);
    
    JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();
    
    String password = object.get("password").getAsString();
    String account = object.get("account").getAsString();
    
    if(!ValueHelper.isEmtpy(password) && !ValueHelper.isEmtpy(account)) {
     res.cookie("Test", "Hallo");
     return isLoginValid(account, password);
    }else
     return false;
   }
  });
  
  get("/valid", new Route() {
   public Object handle(Request req, Response res) throws Exception {
    
    Main.instance().getLog().debug(req.cookie("Test"));
    
    return false;
   }
  });
  
  options("/*",
          new Route() {
     public Object handle(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
         String accessControlRequestHeaders = request
                 .headers("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
         if (accessControlRequestHeaders != null) {
             response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                     accessControlRequestHeaders);
         }

         String accessControlRequestMethod = request
                 .headers("Access-Control-Request-Method");
         if (accessControlRequestMethod != null) {
             response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                     accessControlRequestMethod);
         }
         return "OK";
     }
    });
  before(new Filter() {
   public void handle(Request request, Response response) throws Exception {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   }
  });
 }
```

To understand this: First I call "/login" from my frontend (in this case a React-App with Axios) and than I call "/valid". In my console I get this:

```js
[16:48:47 INFO]: [Portal] null
```

But it should get me the value of the cookie ("Hallo").

What am I doing wrong? Or did I misunderstand something?

Thanks to everyone who will help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem after hours of research. It wasn't a problem of Spark itself. In my application I make the request with axios. Axios apparently works like Ajax or uses it. Therefor I need to add the following to my Axios configuration for the requests:

```
withCredentials: true
```

And in my header configuration within the response I need to add this:

```
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

Now everything works like a charm